# Best multithreading scheme for multiple iterations

Tags: vb.net

I made a complex function that takes in input a huge dataset and ten parameters with discrete value ranges I want to test against on each iteration. What would be the best implementation of multithreading in VB .net?

If I have ten parameters and 5 discrete values for each one, I end with 5^10= 9,765,625 iterations. With a single thread, it's about 4s per pass, 7.5 days total. My computer has 4 cores and 8 threads.

I'd like to report progress: the percentage of passes done. And on each pass or let's say after 10000 passes done, I'd inject the results in a database using ODBC connection.

Until now I used the Parallel.For() method and backgroundworker but I think there must be a better way to do it that would really use 100% of the cores (using threadpool? or creating 8 background workers on the fly?).

Could you put me in the right direction? Which classes should I look at?

Comment: At first I would optimise the math on the single thread, and later would expand to take advantage of multithreading. There are ways to speed up the calculation by making use of optimised Math libraries or just simplify the code.

Comment: [Dataflow (Task Parallel Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) -- [Introduction to Dataflow, Part 1](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/09/introduction-to-dataflow-part-1.html)

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli I already made a code cleanup and optimization on the main function. With my 16Gb RAM, I put my whole 2Gb csv dataset in a collection , so I don't need to read it from the drive on each pass. I am using~12.5 to 15% of my CPU now, most of the big gain would come from using all cores I guess.

Comment: Splitting the dataset and instantiating different threads for each of the collections?

Comment: @alessandromandelli I can't do this because the dataset is a time serie. Maybe I could first make a collection of all combinations of inputs parameters then split it by my number of available threads?

Comment: Yeah, split the input parameters into threads, and give them the dataset to each of them